# How can I sort/group Salesforce leads by geography?

Tags: gis, salesforce

If I had lat/long data for all our leads in Salesforce, is there a way to write a query to group them, or say list all the leads within 10 miles of San Francisco, CA ?

[EDIT: Clarification]
I have thousands of leads with both a full address, and long/lats.
I want to build a query on these leads that will give me all of the leads near San Francisco, CA. This means doing GIS type work within salesforce.

I could of course filter specifically on city, or zipcodes or area code, but this presents some problems when trying to rollup a whole metro area.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need to Reverse GeoCode them with a tool/service. In the past I have used [Maporamas](http://world.maporama.com/) service but it was quite expensive and that was before Google maps and virtual earth existed so I am sure there is something cheaper(free) out there now.... Googling around I have found [this](http://www.viawindowslive.com/Articles/VirtualEarth/Freereversegeocoding.aspx) and [this](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/web/resources-non-google-geocoders?pli=1)

**EDIT:**

OK from What I understand you are trying to calculate the distance between 2 lat/long points. I would start by discounting the ones that where outside you sphere of (lets say) 10 miles. So from your central point you will want to get the the coordinates 10 miles, East, West, South and North. To do this you need to use the [Great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) formula.

From that point you have you Sales Force Data if you wish to break this data up further then you need to order the points by distance from the central point. To do this you need to use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

I am not sure what you language preference is so I just included some examples from SQL(mainly) and C#

[Haversine Formula in C# and in SQL](http://megocode3.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/haversine-formula-in-c/)

[Determine the distance between ZIP codes using C#](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/programming-and-development/?p=634)

[Great Circle SQL](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=81360)

[Great Circle 2](http://www.bigresource.com/MS_SQL-Great-Circle-distance-calculation-AAuK69yL.html#ZWR4HbHJ)

Comment: Let's say I'm trying to build a query, in salesforce, that gives me all the leads within a certain distance of a point expressed in logitude latitude. It would use fields that I added to each salesforce lead that contained the longitude/latitude of the lead.

Comment: Ahh yes, now we're on to something.

The final piece of the puzzle is...  can these values be calculated from within Salesforce ? As in, I don't want to have to update all my leads, through the API, to have new fields for "distance from <x>"

Comment: Yes these can be calculated as demonstrated in the example links. Unless you want to give me some more info about how you would like to go about this IE language specifics then it will be hard to give any more info.....

Answer (score 0):

Use GeoHash.org (either as a web service or implement the algorithm). It hashes your lat-long coords into a form that appears similar for nearby places. For example A may have a hash like "akusDf3af" and B might have a hash like "akusDf3b2" if they are nearby. Then do a SOQL query that looks for places starting with the same n characters as a known location. Your n will determine the radius of the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

These are some great technical solutions that can provide very exact answers, but two things to consider:

- geospatial *proximity* does not map neatly to *responsibility*

Ownership calculation seems to be done best through postal code lookups or other rules that don't allow for gaps or overlaps.  Otherwise, you'll have two (or more) salespeople fighting over leads that are close to both of them, and ignore those leads that are far away from both of them.

So, if you're using geo-calculations like those above to assign ownership, just acknowledge the system will leak and create business rules to accomodate for that.  But a simple postal lookup to define territories (as salesforce's own [territory management](http://www.salesforce.com/community/crm-best-practices/sales-professionals/account-management/territory-management/detail273.jsp) feature does) might be better.

I'd suggest the problem we're trying to solve geospatially is not who owns which lead.  Rather, given all the leads you own, which are nearby?

- maps often offer more data per pixel than columnar reports

Again, geospatial data in a report may not be the best answer.  A lead 50km away, but along a major road, is more interesting than another lead 50km away on the other side of a mountain or lake.  Or a lead close to other leads is more interesting than a lead by itself.

A report can't show this, but a map can.

Salesforce has some great examples of Google Maps integrations.  Instead of a columnar report called "My Nearby Leads", why not a visualforce page, with a google map inside?  You're giving the user far more information than a columnar report could.  They might like it better, and it's easier to implement than trying to calculate some of the equations above.

Just another perspective that may (or may not) be appropriate to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

This post is really old, but is showing up at the top of Google results, so I figured I would post some info to it anyways.

2 nice mapping tools are batchgeo.com and geocod.io. Geocod.io can even give you lat and long coordinates from an address.

If you just need a one time calculation, you can use Excel. Export all your leads with the lat and long. Then go to Google Maps and get the lat and long in decimal degrees for the city center of wherever you want to measure to.

Then use this formula in excel to calculate the distance between the coordinates in miles. Lat1dd and Long1dd are the coordinates for one point, and the lat2dd and long2dd are coordinate points for the other point.

```
=3963*ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-lat1dd))*COS(RADIANS(90-lat2dd))+SIN(RADIANS(90-lat1dd))*SIN(RADIANS(90-lat2dd))*COS(RADIANS(long1dd-long2dd)))
```

After you run it, just sort the results from smallest to largest to get those results that are the closest.

I haven't done this next part yet, but conceptually it should work. We have a field that lists the major market each account is in. Example, Chicago IL. I am going to build a trigger or formula field that essentially says IF(Market="Chicago IL") then use X and Y for the lat and long. These will be hardcoded as the city center for that specific market. The query will then run each individual account's lat and long against the one from the city center to calculate a distance.

If you wanted to break the market into different zones, you could adjust your formula so it uses < and > on the lat and long fields. Everything less than X but greater than Y goes in Zone A, etc.

Hope this helps someone.